# MATLAB: Multiplying a matrix by an unknown scalar (variable.)

Tags: matlab, character, multiplication, scalar

I am trying to multiply a `3x2` matrix with an unknown scalar ( a number in terms of an unknown variable (t).

For instance 10t [<3x2 matrix>]. The variable `t` has no value and should always appear as a "t" instead of any numeric value. How do I get MATLAB to compute the result, while leaving the "t"'s as characters?

Comment: If you have the Symbolic toolbox, you will be able to use that. Check the documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't help at all. What is the Symbolic toolbox and can it actually do what it is I'm trying to do?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.es/products/symbolic/

Answer (score 0):

as David suggested use symbolic toolbox

type the following in matlab: syms t

however if you would describe what you are trying to do in more length, we might find out that you dont even need to use the symbolic toolbox. there might be other alternatives.